# Difference between JRequest::getVar($var) and $var in Joomla/PHP?

Tags: php, joomla

Let me start by saying I know nothing about Joomla or PHP so i might be comparing apples to oranges here but....

I keep seeing `JRequest::getVar($var)` and `$var` in some code i've been looking at.  Can someone explain what the difference between these two is?

According to Joomlas' documentation `getVar` , "Fetches and returns a given variable."  If that is the case why would the following code return different results?

```
echo JRequest::getVar($amount);

echo $amount;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I don't know the first thing about Joomla.*

Looking at [the documentation](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Framework/Environment/JRequest.html#getVar), `JRequest::getVar` fetches values from GET or POST parameters and is supposed to be used like `JRequest::getVar('amount')` (note the argument is a string, not a variable). `echo $amount` and `echo JRequest::getVar($amount)` are of course nowhere near equivalent, the former means "echo the value of `$amount`", the latter "echo the value of a GET or POST variable with the name of the value of `$amount`."

The second parameter `$default` is also very useful:

```
$amount = JRequest::getVar('amount', 100);

// is roughly equivalent to:

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' && isset($_GET['amount'])) {
    $amount = $_GET['amount'];
} else if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['amount'])) {
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
} else {
    $amount = 100;
}
```

Even without the second parameter though, it'll take care of variable cleaning and (un)escaping where necessary, so it's a good idea to use this function to read request parameters.

Comment: It's rather equivalent to `if (isset($_REQUEST['amount']))` (POST form submissions can have variables in $_GET, too, and JRequest/$_REQUEST will catch both of them.) Otherwise great post.

Answer (score 0):

getVar gets a variable from one of PHPs global arrays depending on the hash argument passed.

[Joomla API](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Framework/Environment/JRequest.html#getVar)

[Code](http://api.joomla.org/__filesource/fsource_Joomla-Framework_Environment_joomlaenvironmentrequest.php.html#a94)